# Not getting all data from website using Requests and BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, yahoo-finance

I'm scraping Historical Data on yfinance using BS and requests. The table I'm scraping has 250 rows of data that is from 16 Feb,2023 to 17 Feb, 2022 however I only get 100 rows of data back that is from 16 Feb 2023 to 27 Sep 2022 . I've tried parsing with html,html5lib and lxml but I still get 100 rows of data.

url - https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HSBC/history?period1=1645349926&period2=1676885926&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true

I've tried parsing with html,html5lib and lxml but I still get 100 rows of data.
This is my code so far

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers = {"user-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0"}

url = "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HSBC/history?period1=1645349926&period2=1676885926&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true"

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: That is quite common with such websites. If you inspect the traffic, you'll notice it posts requests for more data when you scroll down.

Comment: okay. Thank you. How do I get all the data?

Comment: I would use the download link on the page.

Comment: That page is pulling some Javascript code which executes and displays the rest of the rows. The complexity required to get that data with Requests surpasses any benefits of using Requests in this scenario. Use Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get that data, using Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time as t
import pandas as pd

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,7200")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)
url = "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HSBC/history?period1=1645349926&period2=1676885926&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true"
driver.get(url) 
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@name="agree"]'))).click()
t.sleep(1)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//body'))).send_keys(Keys.END)
t.sleep(1)
wanted_table = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//table[@data-test="historical-prices"]')))
df = pd.read_html(wanted_table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    Date    Open    High    Low Close*  Adj. close**    Volume
0   17 Feb 2023 37.09   37.40   37.02   37.34   37.34   2052200
1   16 Feb 2023 36.87   37.28   36.87   37.10   37.10   1749900
2   15 Feb 2023 36.66   36.89   36.62   36.88   36.88   1491800
3   14 Feb 2023 36.83   37.29   36.81   37.22   37.22   1525500
4   13 Feb 2023 37.06   37.30   37.05   37.27   37.27   1089000
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
248 25 Feb 2022 35.71   36.31   35.65   36.27   34.78   4604800
249 24 Feb 2022 34.51   34.91   33.87   34.89   33.45   6802700
250 23 Feb 2022 37.33   37.54   36.83   36.95   35.43   3071600
251 22 Feb 2022 37.01   37.35   36.84   37.09   35.56   3822800
252 *Close price adjusted for splits.**Close price adjusted for splits and dividend and/or capital gain distributions.  *Close price adjusted for splits.**Close price adjusted for splits and dividend and/or capital gain distributions.  *Close price adjusted for splits.**Close price adjusted for splits and dividend and/or capital gain distributions.  *Close price adjusted for splits.**Close price adjusted for splits and dividend and/or capital gain distributions.  *Close price adjusted for splits.**Close price adjusted for splits and dividend and/or capital gain distributions.  *Close price adjusted for splits.**Close price adjusted for splits and dividend and/or capital gain distributions.  *Close price adjusted for splits.**Close price adjusted for splits and dividend and/or capital gain distributions.
253 rows × 7 columns
```

Selenium setup is specific to my system. See [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) for a working setup on your own system, and just observe the imports and the part after defining the driver.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try using Selenium.